# Non-writable character issue

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, google-chrome

Im trying to build a list of id's in a textbox. Which works fine in IE and Firefox but not in chrome.

The list that is created is using String.fromCharCode(20) to separate the values. (im using this as the values could be any character so I need to use non writable characters like this and 17)

What happens in Chrome is it seems to remove anything (and including) from the non writable character onwards so if I had

"432@5033"

where @ = the non writable character then it would output "423"

any ideas why chrome has this behaviour!

Comment: really suck on this guys could really do with help on it!

Answer (score 0):

If it is non-printable you probably should b encoding it as something that is representable in plain text. It's difficult to offer any concrete options without knowing the problem you're trying to solve.